# UWP MediaEnded event handler for MediaPlayerElement Throws System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

First off I'm fairly new to UWP so if this question is stupid, my apologies.

What I'm attempting to do is set the event handler for when the song has finnished so that I can start the next one. However when launching I get thrown the following error after the program has started `Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.`

This error traces back to `mediaPlayer.MediaPlayer.MediaEnded += MediaPlayer_MediaEnded1;`

I suspect that I'm incorrectly setting the handler.

```
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaPlayer" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```

Here is my code

```
    List<Song> songs = new List<Song>();
    //private MediaPlayerElement PlayMusic = new MediaPlayerElement();
    private int curSongIndex = 0;
    private IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files;


    public MainPage(){
        this.InitializeComponent();
        slist.ItemClick += Slist_ItemClick;
        mediaPlayer.MediaPlayer.MediaEnded += MediaPlayer_MediaEnded1;

    }

    private void MediaPlayer_MediaEnded1(Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer sender, object args) {
        playNextSong();
    }

    private void Play(Song song) {
        mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(song.File);

        mediaPlayer.MediaPlayer.Play();
        AlbumArt.Source = song.Art;
    }

    private void Slist_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e) {
        for(int i = 0; i < songs.Count; i++) {
            if (e.ClickedItem.Equals(songs[i])) {
                Play(songs[i]);
                curSongIndex = i;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The exception throw when play the next song, right?

Comment: Could share a mini sample could reproduce this issue ?

Comment: I ended up replacing the MediaPlayerElement with MediaElement and now the MediaEnded eventhandler works fine.